# Is it possible for file check to fail if it happened few milliseconds after the file was created?

Tags: java, linux, spring, file

I'm investigating an issue when a Java application fails to find the file

```
if (!event.getCurrentPath().toFile().exists()) {
            logger.info("File in {} does not exist.", event.getCurrentPath());
```

It uses toFile method from Path.java in package java.io.File.

The process runs on the same machine and if I check the time the file was created using the command:

```
ls -alh /dir/file --time-style=full-iso
```

I see that the file is being created before it's being checked.

```
10:00:29.493211000 time file created/updated
10:00:29.538       time file existence was checked
```

Would a timeout help in this case before checking the file? Has this ever happened to anyone? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `Would a timeout help in this case before checking the file` haven't you yet tried?

Comment: I had similar issue, in my case adding few milliseconds of timeout helped

Comment: I would recommend using the newer `java.nio.file.Files` instead of the older java.io facilities. Anyway, how are you creating the file? If it's through an OutputStream, try calling `flush()` before checking it. Also, be aware that checking existence with the `exists()` call does not guarantee the file will still exist when you try to use it. It only means the file existed at the time the `exists` method itself had checked it. By the time the `exists()` method returns, the file may have been deleted by some other thread or process.

Comment: How do you know the "time file existence was checked"?

Comment: @Olivier I knew it thru the logs in the same server, the logger is org.slf4j.Logger object.

Comment: @Alexey not yet because it's an issue in production and I haven't touched any codes yet, was just wondering about the possibility of this as just a timing issue.

Thanks everyone, the comments very insightful!

Comment: Then it's the time of the log. The time of the file check is a bit earlier, and nothing proves that, when you checked for the file existence, it already existed.

Comment: @Olivier that's a good point but I believe the creation process triggered the process which checks the file. I will take a look more! thank you!

Comment: You never specified who creates the file before your application checks its existence (another process or the app itself - in the same thread that does the check or in another one)

Comment: @dekkard the process which creates the file can be in another machine, after that an event is sent and another process checks its existence in another machine. The file is in an nfs directory mounted to those machines. Also, an update, I tried adding a retry mechanism with exponential backoff in that process and it now retries 10 times up to a minute and still wouldn't find the file. I'm really stuck atm. It's very hard to reproduce the error as well, it happens intermittently.